# Species identification - what kind of worm is this?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, invertebrates, pest-control

I am finding these worms in my bathroom since summer arrived. I have been finding these on floor, walls and damp towel I left hung overnight in bathroom couple of times. When these worms are squished, a bang like sound is produced. Can you help me identifying this, is it something to be taken seriously & requires immediate action? Average length of these worms is ~ 1-1,5 inches.  Please find a closeup picture I managed to capture with mobile camera. [image: bathroom/drain worm]

I moved into this house last winter so don't know previous summer history. Anyways I think I should get bathroom drain cleaned.

Edit: Just noticed it has very tiny hair thin, white/ transparent legs, many of them. These legs are barely seen with naked eye. May be they are just hair like things not legs (I don't know proper terminology).

Edit2: origin is Lahore, Pakistan. It's far from sea, open agricultural terrain. Climate is hot.

About movement, no they don't move like earth worms (shortening in length and then stretching). Neither it's snake like. It kinda straight. They also don't have legs as centipedes do, on their sides.

Comment: It might be helpful to include what kind of climate/what region you live in

Comment: Do they move by shortening in length and then extending OR in a snake-like motion moving side to side. This could tell us whether they are a worm or closer to a millipede. Also do they have a hard or slimey exterior

Comment: definitely looks like a millipede (or some other myriapod) with lots of legs. are they really 3 inches long? (my experience is that things crawling in your house often feel bigger than they really are) i don't know about millipedes being problematic, but i don't really know much about pest control. i think you need a better picture for proper identification.

Comment: @hamilthj, origin is Lahore, Pakistan. It's far from sea, open agricultural terrain. Climate is hot. It usually gets as high as 48 degree Celsius in summer. Rains have less frequency (fortnightly, monthly). 
About movement, no they don't move like earth worms (shortening in length and then stretching). Neither it's snake like. It kinda straight. They also don't have legs as centipedes do, on their sides.

Comment: @picapica, yes you're right. They are shorter than 3 inches, way shorter. It has max length of maybe ~1-1.5 inches. I misperceived it's length before. Didn't have a ruler.

Comment: Well, I don't think we'll get much further without much better photos. But my guess is that they just like the damp areas in your bathroom. I doubt they do any harm (other than possibly scaring humans), but if you make it dryer they'll probably leave. Also, you should add the new information to the question to make it easier to find.

Answer (score 0):

It's some sort of millipede. Look closely and you will see hundreds of small white legs sticking out of its sides. Also, you said it goes "Bang" when stepped on; that suggests it has a rigid jointed exoskeleton, something that all millipedes have but, as far as i'm aware, cannot be found in any surviving annelid worm.

Answer (score -3):

This is almost certainly not a millipede as it has no antennae and moves by compressing its body. My money is on insect larva, possibly a drain fly (which would make sense if you regularly see them in the bathroom).

It would be interesting if you could put one in a jar and see what it develops into.